# Is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin(n) \cdot (x_n - x_{n+1})$ defined?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Let's consider sum:

$$L (x_n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin(n) \cdot (x_n - x_{n+1})$$

For $x_n$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|x_n| \le 1$

I want to check whether this functional is well defined i.e. to check if $\forall x_n$ this sum exists.

As already was shown here: [Maximum of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin(n) \cdot (x_n - x_{n+1})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4064746/maximum-of-sum-n-1-infty-sinn-cdot-x-n-x-n1) we know that $L(x_n)$ is bounded, but I'm not sure how to show that this sum exists for any $x_n$ i.e. to show that for any $x_n$ matching the condition $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|x_n|\le1$ $,L(x_n)$ converges.

I was trying to prove it (combining facts that we have $(x_n - x_{n+1})$ differences which strongly suggests to use Cauchy's theorem and condition on $x_n$ : $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n| \le 1$). But I end up with nothing. Could you please give me a hand with telling if this expression converges for any $x_n$ ?

Comment: Use this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59589/show-that-a-n-sum-limits-k-1n-sin-k-is-bounded and cauchy-schwartz inequality

Comment: Doesn't the sum converge absolutely?  $$|\sin(n)(x_n-x_{n+1})|\leq|x_n|+|x_{n+1}|$$

Comment: @Lucian: It shows that the series is *absolutely* convergent.

Comment: Yup thank you very much ;))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this series converges absolutely. This is because $|\sin(n) (x_{n + 1} - x_n)| \leq |x_{n + 1} - x_n| \leq |x_{n + 1}| + |x_n|$, and

$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty |x_{n + 1}| + |x_n|$

converges.

Answer (score 0):

For any $\epsilon>0$, just choose $N_0$ large enough such that $\sum\limits_{n=N_0}^{N_1}|x_n| <\frac1{2}\epsilon$ for all $N_1 \gt N_0$

and you get  $\sum\limits_{n=N_0}^{N_1}|\sin(n)(x_n-x_{n+1})| \le \sum\limits_{n=N_0}^{N_1}|\sin(n)x_n| +\sum\limits_{n=N_0}^{N_1}|\sin(n) x_{n+1}| < \epsilon$

so $\left|\sum\limits_{n=N_0}^{N_1}\sin(n)(x_n-x_{n+1})\right| < \epsilon$

so the partial sums are a Cauchy sequence

and thus the overall series converges.